# Using Shiny to plot database values

Tags: sql, r, shiny, rodbc

I have looked through many different posts on SQL and RODBC, but for some reason I cannot seem to figure this out.  I have created a Shiny App.  A user will enter the date range of choice and a plot should show with the queried data.  However, this does not work.  I have tried hard coding the days in the SQL string and that WORKS.  So I have pinpointed the problem in the dates not properly carrying over to the sql string.  I have tried `paste0()` , but read that `sprintf()` works better for having multiple values.  BTW, I am querying a PI server.  Here is my code:

Server

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)



shinyServer(function(input, output) {

Connection <- odbcConnect(dsn = "PIWHI", believeNRows = FALSE, rows_at_time =1)

x <- reactive({input$range[1]})
y <- reactive({input$range[2]})


query <- sprintf("SELECT time, value
          FROM picomp
          WHERE tag = 'A80100'
          AND time >= DATE('%s')
          AND time <= DATE('%s')", x,y)

LineX <- sqlQuery(WhitingPI, query)


Gravity <- LineX$VALUE
Time <- LineX$TIME

output$den <- renderPlot({plot(Time,Gravity)})


}
)
```

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  # Application title
  headerPanel("Monitoring Tool"),

  sidebarPanel(
   dateRangeInput('range',
                  label = 'Date input: dd-mm-yyyy. Controls start and end of date range input in main panel.',
                  start = Sys.Date()-1, end = Sys.Date(),
                  format = "dd-M-yyyy", startview = 'year', language = 'en', weekstart = 1),

   sliderInput("sigmacoef", "Confidence Level",min = 0, max = 5, value = 2, step =0.5),
   submitButton("Update View")
   ),
  mainPanel(
   plotOutput("den")

  )
    ))
```

Comment: The value returned by `reactive` is a function. `x` and `y` in `query` would need to be called as `x()` and `y()`. Also `query` itself and related quantities would probably need to be `reactive`.

Comment: jdharrison - I followed your suggestion and added parentheses to x and y.  I also made query reactive, but I am still facing the same issue.